# What will happen if i do not add waitgroup in go routine?

Tags: go

In the Golang server(using echo framework) in one of the endpoint i am triggering some function using go routine, but i am not adding any waitgroup to that go routine.

```
server.router.PATCH(path.Join(server.Config.APIPath, "/dummy"), h.SomeFunc)

// /dummy
func (h * )SomeFunc() error {
go func() {
someTask()
}
}
```

every where it suggests i should have written like

```
func (h * )SomeFunc() error {
var wg.syncWaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
someTask()
wg.done()
}
wg.wait()
}
```

What will happen if i did not add waitgroups as suggested ? is it going to cause memory leak ?

Comment: Explanation for downVote would be much appreciated, as it will allow me to clarify the problem

Comment: If you add no code, nothing will happen at that point. That could be a problem: if you need *something* to happen—such as waiting for goroutines to finish—then doing *nothing* is the wrong thing.

Comment: A possible explanation for downvotes is that you haven't really asked a useful question because you've boiled it down to a situation with no context and made up function names which have no obvious purpose. If you don't wait for `someTask` to finish, then `SomeFunc` won't wait, that's all waitgroups are for. It's entirely situational whether that's actually a problem. It might be desired to wait, it might be desired not to wait. It might be a critical bug to not wait or it might be completely benign.

Answer (score 1):

It will not cause a memory leak. However, it is likely that the goroutine will not finish until the function returns, causing the request handling to complete. If the result of the goroutine is required to build the response to the client, that means the client will get empty or incomplete response. The waitgroup ensures that the goroutine completes before the `SomeFunc` returns.

If however, the handler is used to start some asynchronous process that will continue running after the handler returns, you should use the version without the `WaitGroup`.

Comment: Yes it is just to start some asynchronous process. I am not understanding how that routine will know that it has completed the work ? and allocate that thread for further use ?

Comment: The goroutine finishes when it returns, in this case, when `someTask` returns. The waitgroup is used to stop one goroutine to wait for others to finish.